# Unable to access contextType via this.context in React 16

Tags: reactjs

Was trying out the new Context API and am running into an issue where i am not able to accesss the context created via `React.createContext` in my class .

A simple example is

```
const AppContext = React.createContext("blue"); /* creating context  */


export class App extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext; /* setting context type */

  render() {
    console.log(this.context); /* trying to access */
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My expectation is the `console.log` should print "blue" , but i just get `{}`. I am able to access the context value via `AppContext.Consumer` though.

Where am i going wrong?

More detailed example can be seen here - https://codesandbox.io/s/217jml9nlr

Comment: Issue with version number.. my bad :\

Answer (score 4):

You haven't updated `react-dom` to the same version i.e 16.6 as React and hence you see this unexpected behaviour. Both react and react-dom should use the same version

`static contextType` api is supported only from version 16.6 onwards.

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/23o57mmy00)